# How can I assign a javascript variable to the session value

Tags: php, javascript, session

```
function changeClient(s) {
if(s.value!=0)
{
    document.location.href = "map.php?c="+s.value;
}
```

I have to assign the value of s to a session variable $_SESSION['id'].How can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['c']
```

set the GET parameter you sent to a session variable.

Comment: Ya..i put $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['c'];and in another page i have retrive this value..if(isset($_SESSION['id']))

{$g['client_id']=$SESSION['id'];}..but it doesn't enters to the if condition.

Comment: Did you use `session_start()` on top of both the pages?

Comment: Check if the JS code is being able to send the data properly, and verify by `echo`ing the SESSION variable just after assigning.

Comment: ohk, welcome. now you can mark the most useful answer as correct by ticking the small tickmark on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign client side variable(Javascript) to server side variable(PHP).

You have to use ajax to do this.

```
<script>
function assignJsValueToPHPSession()
{
 var jsVar = 1;
 $.ajax({
  type:post,
  url: "test.html",
  data: 'sessionjsvar=' + jsVar,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
 });
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['phpvalue'] = $_POST['sessionjsvar'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set cookie using javascript and the same cookie will be accessible in server side variable(PHP).

```
$.cookie("name1", "test"); // emample 1
$.cookie("name1", "test", { expires: 7 }); // emample 2
$.cookie("name1", "test", { path: '/User', expires: 7 }); // emample 3
```

**Get a cookie**

alert( $.cookie("test") );

//In PHP

```
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
print)r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['c']
```

Just check `c` is really in the URL first.

Comment: I think it's actually $_GET['c'] no?

Comment: Ya..i put $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['c'];and in another page i have retrive this value..if(isset($_SESSION['id']))

{$g['client_id']=$SESSION['id'];}..but it doesn't enters to the if condition.

Comment: Now it enters into if condition.i think problem is in $g['client_id']=$SESSION['id'];